# If the IAVI G001 HIV vaccine proves itself, why would it work?

Tags: hiv, vaccine

The IAVI G001 HIV vaccine trial looks promising.

If it works, will it work by preventing a single cell from being infected, or by allowing the body to attack infected cells?

What I'm trying to understand is if a person living with HIV for years can't develop immunity, why might the vaccine succeed?

Comment: There are a lot of sources of information about the vaccine that include information about how it works. Have you read those explanations, and if so, what are you not understanding?

Comment: Yes, I've read them but they either didn't answer my question or were too technical to be understood by a layman.

Comment: Can you please add more background to include specifics about what you've learned and how that doesn't answer your question?